# How to merge two partials to a complete object?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that requires all props. However, creating the object is a two-step process. Therefore I am planning to create 2 `Partial` versions of the object, and then merge them together to satisfy the non-partial interface. Example:

```
interface IComplete {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

const part1: Partial<IComplete> = {
    a: 'hello'
}

const part2: Partial<IComplete> = {
    b: 'world'
}

const together: IComplete = {
    ...part1,
    ...part2
}
```

Even though `together` is always complete, the compiler complains:

```
Type '{ a?: string; b?: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IComplete'.
   Property 'a' is optional in type '{ a?: string; b?: string; }' but required in type 'IComplete'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IComplete%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20part1%3A%20Partial%3CIComplete%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20%27hello%27%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20part2%3A%20Partial%3CIComplete%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%27world%27%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20together%3A%20IComplete%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20...part1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20...part2%0D%0A%7D)

Is there a recommended way to achieve this? It is important for my case that the interface `IComplete` is *not* made partial, i.e. the props a and b are never null or undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@RyanCavanaugh's answer is good.  One way to let type inference do its work while still getting the benefits of the compiler ensuring that `part1` and `part2` are `Partial<IComplete>` is to use a helper function as below:

```
interface IComplete {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c: (x: string) => number,
  d: (x: number) => string
}

// helper function
const asPartialIComplete = <T extends Partial<IComplete>>(t: T) => t;

const part1 = asPartialIComplete({
  a: 'hello',
  c: (x) => x.length
})

const part2 = asPartialIComplete({
  b: 'world',
  d: (x) => x + ""
});

const together: IComplete = {
  ...part1,
  ...part2
}
```

In the above, both `part1` and `part2` are constrained by `asPartialIComplete` to be valid `Partial<IComplete>` objects (so the parameters of the `c` and `d` methods are inferred as `string` and `number` respectively).  But the types of `part1` and `part2` are narrow enough for the compiler to realize that `typeof part1 & typeof part2` is `IComplete`.

Hope that also helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I don't see the benefit of using this function over just writing `const part1: Partial<IComplete> = ...`. That works for me in TS 4.8.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to remove the type annotations and let type inference do its work:

```
interface IComplete {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

const part1 = {
    a: 'hello'
}

const part2 = {
    b: 'world'
}

const together: IComplete = {
    ...part1,
    ...part2
}
```

This does have certain deleterious effects, e.g. parameters in function expressions in `part1` or `part2` won't get inferred types.

Instead you can use `Pick` - unfortunately you do have to write out the keys that you're picking from each type when using this approach:

```
interface IComplete {
    a: string,
    b: string,
    c: number
}

const part1: Pick<IComplete, "a"> = {
    a: 'hello'
}

const part2: Pick<IComplete, "b" | "c"> = {
    b: 'world',
    c: 43
}

const together: IComplete = {
    ...part1,
    ...part2
}
```

Comment: Why it does not work with spread operator? Eg here I have T & Partial<T> as a result of createState function https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAUM5DAcwC5kBnMKUI-ZGAewbMupFoF9dc4AjVxGGQIANnHLlkAFQiUAPFIB8OOgAcArrxHAEyPgIRDKmCGSkBuOsKgQT6EwApVUBqrIAFOFDDA4IhYoAlCoEoTZg6lAgOAB0cWAAFsDkMcaQADTIcTHOrhyWBFwcQA

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I do not fully understand why typescript transpiler does not permit that syntax.

But the below codes can bypass it and achieve what you want.

```
interface IComplete {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

const part1: Partial<IComplete> = {
    a: 'hello'
}

const part2: Partial<IComplete> = {
    b: 'world'
}

const together: IComplete = {
    ...part1,
    ...part2
} as IComplete
```

Comment: Curious to know what the disadvantage of this solution is, if any. It seems to be the most readable.

Comment: There is no static verification that `part1` and `part2` collectively contributed *all* of the keys of `IComplete`

Comment: The disadvantage is that `together` might not be an `IComplete`, as you can see if you change `part2` to be `{a: 'whoops'}` instead.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! I'm having a hard time selecting an accepted answer... let me know if you see a clear winner.

Comment: Yes, those are fair criticisms. My answer does not guarantees correct type which can prevent unnoticed bug. I think @jcalz's anwser is exemplary anwser which satisfies the mission of typescript.

Comment: Hmmm, I think this is also something that Typescript *should* do. In your example it should show a warning when not supplying all the properties of the interface and the fact that it doesn't in the case mentioned is quite a failure. I'm wondering if this is a known bug.