# Is there a way for TypeScript to know when a Partial becomes complete?

Tags: typescript

Sometimes I have [partials](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and use them in the process of creating an object that matches the extended version of some interface. For example, if I have:

```
export interface Thing {
  someProperty: string
}
```

and

```
export interface ThingWithMoreProperties extends Thing {
  newProperty: string;
}
```

And I'll run code like:

```
const thingsWithMoreProperties = things.map((thing) => {
  const thingWithMoreProperties: Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties> = thing
  thingWithMoreProperties.newProperty = 'swag';
  return thingWithMoreProperties;
});
```

At this point, TypeScript will show the `thingsWithMoreProperties` type as `Partial<Array<ThingWithMoreProperties>>`.

What I end up doing is using [a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell TypeScript the `Partial` is now complete:

```
const thingsWithMoreProperties = things.map((thing) => {
  const thingWithMoreProperties: Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties> = thing
  thingWithMoreProperties.newProperty = 'swag';
  return thingWithMoreProperties;
}) as Array<ThingWithMoreProperties>;
```

Is there a better way of doing this - without using `as` - so TypeScript can realise that all of the properties of what was the `Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties>` now exist, and the `Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties>` is now just a `ThingWithMoreProperties`?

Comment: Fundamentally, assigning a value to an optional property _never_ changes the type of the variable; the property remains optional. You can type-safely spread (or `Object.assign`) to the full object if you're starting with some _known_ missing properties (e.g. with https://stackoverflow.com/a/51275608/3001761) or providing values for _every_ property: https://tsplay.dev/NaDGnw. It's not clear what `Thing` or `asyncMap` are (or why _anything's_ `async` here) but if you `return { ...thing, newProperty: "swag" }` the compiler knows at least that property exists https://tsplay.dev/Wzx21N.

Comment: You mean `[] as Thing[]`? That's just to create a minimal starting point, so the type of the `thing` parameter in the `map` callback can be inferred.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK that works https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBUAW4DmqDewqqA9gDYAmACjCQA6wQCeAXKgM4Qy4DcwAvsGBQAHnRIwIqcNHjI0WXAHUQETAFkJUGvUYgo7VKOhgKhxWDyFiYKAHcdDSaw5deAoUhJhOqNblQAXgIiUkpHRhcAcjtMBGgAN1goj2AvHyl-S0NggG0snABdT29fAvYVNU0YbVonCH12NgscSo0tCMlG3MKgv2xsgDoAWwQ6AApxgoBKIIA+VHHrYlRBtYKAGlCbe07mNgAidjsEHAOt-mnpviA still trying to figure out why...

Comment: TS doesn't narrow non-union object types by assignment or by property setting.  If you want such behavior you'll need to write your own assertion functions and refrain from annotating a non-union type.  The line `const thingWithMoreProperties : Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties> = thing;` throws away the information that `thing` already is a `Thing` and not just a `Partial<Thing>`.  (more)

Comment: (continued) If you want to annotate anything it would be `Thing & { newProperty?: string }`, so at least it starts off as "mostly complete".  With that in mind, [see this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZvO9m). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Small TS playground example showing both @jonrsharpe's example (destructuring) which works versus direct assignment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBUAW4DmqDewqqA9gDYAmACjCQA6wQCeAXKgM4Qy4DcwAvsGBQAHnRIwIqcNHjI0WXAHUQETAFkJUGvUYgo7VKOhgKhxWDyFiYKAHcdDSaw5deAoUhJhOqNblQAXgIiUkpHRhcAcjtMBGgAN1goj2AvHyl-S0NggG0snABdT29fAvYVNU0YbVonCH12AEY2CxxKjS0IyUbcwqC-bGyAOgBbBDoACkmCgEoggD5USetUYfWCgBpQ2wc6yLYAInY7BBxD7f5Z2b400syhnArVTpruhoMAJgHysYnpuaLELEdJlR4daq1XQ9AxsKgIHoIMgAHjaEK6+xh7CWwQKoQK6LemI+7GGu3eTAGUROZyifGINQgAFcYGBBsoXpD3o0+Fd6aggA

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, the second like re: type info being thrown away helps clarify - that would make a good answer.

Comment: You could also do `return thingWithMoreProperties as ThingWithMoreProperties;`. It's still a type assertion though. I'd say you're basically doing it right already, and Typescript shouldn't do what you're asking.

Comment: @jcalz your TS playground examples both help too - answer away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is largely predicated on the fact that the type of a value is *static* and does not change depending on the state of the value.  It can't deal with arbitrary type mutations. It has some ability to perform type [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) based on [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis), but these are in very specific circumstances, largely centered around filtering [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

For example, [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) works on union types (e.g., `let x: string | number = "abc";` narrows `x` to `string` until reassignment).  But `Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties>` isn't a union type, so the assignment `const thingWithMoreProperties: Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties> = thing` doesn't narrow anything.  That means, as far as the compiler knows, `thingWithMoreProperties` doesn't have *any* of the properties set, including the one from `Thing`.

And property setting like `thingWithMoreProperties.newProperty = "swag"` only serves to narrow the property itself, and not the containing object (although there is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) to allow that).  So again, `thingWithMoreProperties` stays resolutely `Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties>` and no information about its state is available.

---

TypeScript does have ways of letting you customize control flow analysis behavior a bit... via [custom type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).  As long as you can describe the behavior as a *narrowing* of a function argument, you can probably simulate it.

For example, the concept of "adding a property should narrow the object type" can be represented by the following assertion function:

```
function addProp<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey, V>(obj: T, k: K, v: V):
  asserts obj is T & { [P in K]: V } {
  (obj as any)[k] = v;
}
```

You can see it in action:

```
const obj = { a: 1 };
addProp(obj, "b", "abc");
obj; // const obj: { a: number; } & { b: string; }
```

So if we use that and give up annotating, you'll get the behavior you're looking for:

```
const thingsWithMoreProperties: ThingWithMoreProperties[] = things.map(thing => {
  addProp(thing, "newProperty", 'swag');
  return thing;
}); // okay
```

Or you can annotate as something that knows everything from `Thing` is present:

```
const thingsWithMoreProperties: ThingWithMoreProperties[] = things.map(thing => {
  const thingWithMoreProperties: Thing & Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties> = thing;
  addProp(thingWithMoreProperties, "newProperty", 'swag');
  return thingWithMoreProperties;
}); // okay
```

So, to that extent, you can get the compiler to understand that a `Partial<X>` gradually builds up to an `X`:

```
const t: Partial<ThingWithMoreProperties> = {};
addProp(t, "someProperty", "abc")
addProp(t, "newProperty", "def");
const u: ThingWithMoreProperties = t; // okay
```

But it's clunky.

---

If you can help it, you should switch away from trying to represent state mutation in the type system, and toward using immutable data. The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is one such way to describe property setting.  Instead of `obj.prop = val`, you can write `newObj = {...obj, prop: val}`, so `obj` remains unchanged:

```
const thingsWithMoreProperties: ThingWithMoreProperties[] = things.map(thing => {
  return { ...thing, newProperty: "swag" };
});
```

TypeScript can much more easily handle strong typings for things that don't change, than it can for state mutation.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99#code/FAiWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAKgCwgcwOqiRYCyA9rNAAqxkAOcko0AzmtAB4zgAmb2eNAG9gaNOGgB3GvUYBPAFxoWkWHgDcwAL7AIMBCnQDwuYaOVkAttVoNYkRctV5tIeAFdwyJmXBpEPDwydAA8GOxc0LxsZABGAFbQ3gA0aADSEdx8aMHyadByqQBqAHwAFHHxShipANZKaakAbkpFAJQK5ogsLIwxCWig-GgAZMJoANpUg35pALqtaFpmYhUD3f7gcm0TtXNoALxoTZo6wMi+KmiVh+OISgCMS5oBQbZr8akARLFf34ixZBfNqaSrqNAAeghaAu4CulSUQn8SnA7kssTg4OWYyRsSUKjUJixICh4jIm3AZEgiB84GAHi8tLQ8DIZDKxDwLGqOBMEzmbRWMMukDQHJMLEIxHIlFy9mYXMwPIIRFIFBssjlrD5tzFuBYADpLIg6OylYcSoKxK9gqa8N8JNJbPI-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-lLF1+qIOpABioAcNAPBNkF0IhRQEVRTkqluhWo3jTwyU8GQrBkiKnBDCKviirF6DFYS9WNYlsBlecr6QEoGFythuF4NJyEsCRwiBcAlH0Oy3y2cx-yAsC32BDakCMY6hFyC6Xw8NA8DApo0Yiu4qGvXR8o6tN1y1IgcgktCLB0JQASnoyF5oFeABet4KsYuCPoKKNvpyGOEb+iovXxdnAfspGcnJJq6lBfpoFxwbjPq0u6qkKnQ-OHpep14YcaJ8aJsmdPswJrBC2UClKcWTGqep1Z1g2ulth2zauEAA)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a typed assignement function:

(note that you need to provide `.map<>` generic if you want you result be `ThingWithMoreProperties` rather then `{foo: string, bar: string}` and to have type check)

```
function set<T extends {}, K extends PropertyKey, V>(o: T, k: K, v: V): Omit<T, K> & Record<K, V> {
  return Object.assign(o, { [k]: v }) as any;
}
const assign = Object.assign as <T, O>(t: T, o: O) => Omit<T, keyof O> & O;

const thingsWithMoreProperties3 = things.map<ThingWithMoreProperties>((thing) => {
  // will work for non-existing and optional keys (as it's typed as `<T, V>(t, v) => T & V`)
  return Object.assign(thing, {newProperty: 'swag'});
});
const thingsWithMoreProperties4 = things.map<ThingWithMoreProperties>((thing) => {
  return set(thing, 'newProperty', 'swag');
});
const thingsWithMoreProperties5 = things.map<ThingWithMoreProperties>((thing) => {
  return assign(thing, {newProperty: 'swag'});
});
```